# How to define a function accepting exactly three characters?

Tags: postgresql, functions, plpgsql

I tried this:

```
create or replace function c3 (arg char(3))
  returns void
  language plpgsql as
$$
begin
  raise notice 'Value: %', arg;
end;
$$;
```

But it accepts more than three characters:

```
select c3('1234');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data type modifiers in function parameters (as in `char(3)`) are ignored by `CREATE FUNCTION`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-NOTES)

> The full SQL type syntax is allowed for declaring a function's
> arguments and return value. However, parenthesized type modifiers
> (e.g., the precision field for type numeric) are discarded by `CREATE FUNCTION`. Thus for example `CREATE FUNCTION foo (varchar(10))` ... is
> exactly the same as `CREATE FUNCTION foo (varchar)` ....

You *could* still work with your original function, by adding an explicit cast in the call:

```
SELECT c3('1234'::char(3));  -- explicit cast
```

But that's just putting lipstick on a pig.

#### Proper solution

Add an explicit test:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION c3 (arg text)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF length(arg) > 3 THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Input too long: >>%<<', arg;
   END IF;

   RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', arg;
END
$func$;
```

**Or** silently cast or truncate the input to avoid the exception:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION c3 (arg text)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   arg := left(arg, 3);  -- one of several ways

   RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', arg;
END
$func$;
```

And never use the legacy data type `char(N)` (even if that's not the immediate problem here). See:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/939860)

Comment: I am wondering if I should care at all about the length check. Theoretically I could wait until the corresponding column check raises an error. Is it good practice to fail early or is it advisable to not care about?

Comment: @Typically, it's best to fail early. But that all depends on the details of your case.